# How to create a grid to do kriging interpolation that correspond to areas in a map having actual observations?

Tags: r, interpolation, grids-graticules, kriging

I need to do kriging interpolation but wanted to have the interpolation in areas where I have actual data; not across the whole map.

This is my example.

Here is the base map (shp file in a .zip file): http://www.filedropper.com/lpr000b16ae

Here is the data I want to interpolate: http://www.filedropper.com/yielddata

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(gstat)
library(stars)

## a) Defining the projection of the maps
proj_lambert <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

## b) Map Canada selected provinces.
canada.map <- st_read("C:/Users/rotundjo/Desktop/lpr_000b16a_e/lpr_000b16a_e.shp") %>% 
  filter(PRNAME == "Manitoba" |
           PRNAME == "Alberta" |
           PRNAME == "Saskatchewan") %>%
  st_transform(proj_lambert )

## c) Data set
data.yield <- read_csv("C:/Users/rotundjo/Desktop/yield.data.csv")
data.yield.coords <- data.yield %>% select(lat, long)
data.yield.data <- data.yield %>% select(av.yield)

#### Creating LAT LONG SpatialPoints
coordinates(data.yield.coords) = c("long", "lat")
proj4string(data.yield.coords) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # 4326 is the EPSG identifier of WGS84.

### Converting the LAT LONG to the lambert CRS shown above
lambert_data.yield.coords = spTransform(data.yield.coords, proj_lambert)
lambert_data.yield.coords = as.data.frame(lambert_data.yield.coords)

#### Adding the Type column back to the data frame, with the new polar coordinates
lambert_data = cbind(lambert_data.yield.coords, data.yield.data)


coordinates(data.yield) = c("long", "lat")
proj4string(data.yield) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
data.yield = spTransform(data.yield, proj_lambert)
data.yield.sf <- st_as_sf(data.yield, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = proj_lambert)


## d) Variogram fit
v = variogram(av.yield~1, data.yield.sf)
plot(v, plot.numbers = TRUE)

v.m = fit.variogram(v, vgm("Sph", psill = 3, range = 3000000, nugget = 1))
plot(v, v.m, plot.numbers = FALSE)

## e) Building a empty grid
st_bbox(canada.map) %>%
  st_as_stars(dx = 1000) %>%
  st_set_crs(proj_lambert) %>%
  st_crop(canada.map) -> grd

## f) Kriging interpolation
k = krige(av.yield~1, data.yield.sf, grd, v.m)

## g) plotting all together
library(viridis)
ggplot() + 
  geom_stars(data = k, aes(fill = var1.pred, x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_sf(data = canada.map, color = "gray", fill="transparent") +
  geom_point(data = lambert_data, aes(x = long, y = lat), size = 0.1, color = "gray") +
  theme_bw()

library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot() + 
  geom_stars(data = k, 
             aes(fill = cut(var1.pred,breaks=c(0,20,21,22,23,24,Inf),
                            labels = c("Below 20",
                                       ">20-21", 
                                       ">21-22", 
                                       ">22-23",
                                       ">23-24",
                                       "Above 24")),
                            x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_sf(data = canada.map, color = "gray", fill="transparent") +
  geom_point(data = lambert_data, aes(x = long, y = lat), size = 0.1, color = "gray") +
  theme_bw()
```

This is my result:

[image]

But I would like to have the interpolation made only in the areas having actual observations. That is, the `grd` that is defined above should be defined by an area defined by the actual points. The expected result should be something like this:

[image]

The white stripped are should be part of the `grd` for the interpolation.

I was not able to define the grid area for interpolation to be restricted somehow to the areas where there are actual observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be for you to draw a polygon that defines the bit you don't want, and use `st_difference` to subtract that from the `canada.map` polygons. Then apply the same process you have done with that new polygonal region to get a new `grd`.

Here's how to draw a polygon and then cut it:

```
plot(canada.map$geom)
# (add your data point to the plot as well for guidance)
cutp = locator(type="p")
```

`locator` will then let you click points on the display. Draw your region and go round outside the region to complete it (actually use `type="l"` which will draw lines as you go instead of points). Mouse button 2 to finish. Don't try and close it up as a complete ring, we'll do that next....

[image]

that returns a list of x and y coordinate vectors, so lets mash it into an `sf` polygon with the correct CRS:

```
# make a 2 column matrix:
cutm = cbind(cutp$x, cutp$y)
# add the first coord to the end to make a loop:
cutm = rbind(cutm, cutm[1,])
# make an sf object with the crs:
cutpol = st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cutm)))
st_crs(cutpol) = st_crs(canada.map)
```

and now we can difference it:

```
canada.cut = st_difference(canada.map, cutpol)
plot(canada.cut$geom)
```

[image]

repeating your workflow should produce outputs constrained to this cut region just as your outputs were constrained to the original polygon region.

Other possibilities include automatically defining the region from your data, eg by creating a merged buffer of some distance from your data points, or using a convex or concave hull based on your data points.

Comment: Thanks so much @Spacedman. Great answer!